# How can lapply work with addressing columns as unknown variables?

Tags: r, lapply

So, I have a list of strings named `control_for`. I have a data frame `sampleTable` with some of the columns named as strings from `control_for` list. And I have a third object `dge_obj` (DGElist object) where I want to append those columns. What I wanted to do - use lapply to loop through `control_for` list, and for each string, find a column in `sampleTable` with the same name, and then add that column (as a factor) to a DGElist object. For example, for doing it manually with just one string, it looks like this, and it works:

```
group <- as.factor(sampleTable[,3])
dge_obj$samples$group <- group
```

And I tried something like this:

```
lapply(control_for, function(x) {
  x <- as.factor(sampleTable[, x])
  dge_obj$samples$x <- x
}
```

Which doesn't work. I guess the problem is that R can't recognize addressing columns like this. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you post an example `sampleTable` in `dput` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two base R ways of doing it. The data set is the example of `help("DGEList")` and a mock up data.frame `sampleTable`.

Define a vector `common_vars` of the table's names in `control_for`. Then create the new columns.

```
library(edgeR)

sampleTable <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 5:8, no = letters[21:24])
control_for <- c("a", "b")

common_vars <- intersect(control_for, names(sampleTable))
```

### 1. `for` loop

```
for(x in common_vars){
  y <- sampleTable[[x]]
  dge_obj$samples[[x]] <- factor(y)  
}
```

### 2. `*apply` loop.

```
tmp <- sapply(sampleTable[common_vars], factor)
dge_obj$samples <- cbind(dge_obj$samples, tmp)
```

This code can be rewritten as a one-liner.

---

### Data

```
set.seed(2021)
y <- matrix(rnbinom(10000,mu=5,size=2),ncol=4)
dge_obj <- DGEList(counts=y, group=rep(1:2,each=2))
```